# How do you define this structure in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript newbie here. I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find an answer.

How do I define the structure that would make this code valid. It's some sort of function with a property:

```
const theThing = createThing(7, 2);
theThing(); // returns a whole number between 1 and 22
theThing.toStringProp();
```

Comment: The question is "how to implement a callable interface with additional methods", *possibly* with an additional question of "how to restrict the return type of the callable portion to a number between 1 and 22".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callables are interfaces with ["bare" or unnamed method signatures](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/callable.html):

```
type ValidNumber = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;

interface Thing {
  (): ValidNumber
  toStringProp(): string
}
```

*Constructing* them is not entirely type-safe, so it's best to do a bit of extra work with helpers:

```
interface ThingCallable {
  (): ValidNumber
}

interface ThingProps {
  toStringProp(): string
}

type Thing = ThingCallable & ThingProps;

const thingCallable: ThingCallable = () => 7;
const thingMixin = { toStringProp() { return 'hi' } };
const thing: Thing = Object.assign(thingCallable, thingMixin);
```

Or, as suggested in the duplicate question using `Object.assign` directly:

```
interface Thing {
  (): ValidNumber
  toStringProp(): string
}

const thing: Thing = Object.assign(
  // Must be a valid () => ValidNumber
  () => 9,
  // Must be a valid superset of the other properties in Thing
  {
    toStringProp() { return 'hello'; }
  }
);
```